# How to Capture Selected CheckBox Items and Update a List with MVVM in .Net maui

Tags: c#, mvvm, maui

This is my first time working on a MAUI app and struggling with a scenario where I need to capture the selected CheckBox items from a collection and store their relevant Section objects into a list when I click a button (I've seen some people add to the model  boolean property to see if the item is selected or not but i didn't do that) .

I have a CollectionView that displays a list of Sections:

```
<CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding Sections}"
                                Grid.Row="1">
                                <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <HorizontalStackLayout>
                                        <!-- I don't know what to add to the check box to handle the selecting event -->
                                            <CheckBox Color="#0B4C90"/>
                                            <Label Text="{Binding SectionName}"
                                       FontSize="20"
                                       FontAttributes="Bold"
                                       TextColor="#0B4C90"/>
                                        </HorizontalStackLayout>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                            </CollectionView>
                        </Border>
<Buton Text="Get Sections"/>
```

Here is the Section Model : (i called it 'Rayon' because it wouldn't let me name it Section)

```
public class Rayon
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string SectionName { get; set; } = null!;
        public ICollection<SectionSupplier> SectionSuppliers { get; set; } = null!;
        public ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; } = null!;
    }`
And here is my view model : 
`public partial class CreateSupplierPageViewModel : ObservableObject
{

/* This is the list that i want to Add or remove Sections from whenever i check or uncheck one of the checkboxs */ 
    private ObservableCollection<Rayon> _selectedSections;
        public ObservableCollection<Rayon> SelectedSections
        {
            get => _selectedSections;
            set
            {
                _selectedSections = value;
            }
        }

        public ObservableCollection<Rayon> Sections { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<Rayon>();

public async Task GetSectionsList()
        {
            var sectionList = new List<Rayon>();

            var sectionUrl = "https://localhost:7282/api/Sections/GetSections";

            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                var Apiresponse = await client.GetAsync(sectionUrl);

                if (Apiresponse.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
                {
                    var content = await Apiresponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    sectionList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Rayon>>(content);
                }

            }

            if (sectionList?.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (var section in sectionList)
                {
                    Sections.Add(section);
                }
            }
        }

/*This method is used simply because i couldn't call GetSectionsList directly in the constructor to avoid deadlocks */

public static async Task<CreateSupplierPageViewModel> Create()
        {
            var it = new CreateSupplierPageViewModel();
            await it.Initialize();
            return it;
        }

        private async Task Initialize()
        {
            await GetSectionsList();
        }
        public CreateSupplierPageViewModel()
        {
            SelectedSections = new ObservableCollection<Rayon>();
        }
}
```

I'm looking for guidance on how to capture the selected Sections when the button is clicked. Any help or code samples would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

I tried Looking in the net for a solution but whatever i find just confuses me because i don't know what or where should i place the code that i find in the solutions . i tried also using chat gpt but it whatever solution it provides it doesn,t work

Comment: The correct method is to add a bool property to your model.  Otherwise you can use CollectionViews built in multi select instead of checkboxes

Comment: "I've seen some people add to the model boolean property to see if the item is selected or not but I didn't do that" - unless you have very very very solid reason not to do it, I recommend that you reconsider. Getting a selection list from the original collection is one line LINQ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can add a bool field to the model (`Rayon.cs`) of list `Sections` and bind it to the `CheckBox`. This is also the method we often use.

Of course, if you really want to trigger the selecting event, you can use [EventToCommandBehavior](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/maui/behaviors/event-to-command-behavior) to achieve this.

I created a demo and tried to achieve this function with two methods above.

You can refer to the following code:

**MainPage.xaml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:viewdels="clr-namespace:MauiCheckListviewApp.ViewModes"
             xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2022/maui/toolkit"
             x:Class="MauiCheckListviewApp.MainPage">

    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <viewdels:MyViewModel></viewdels:MyViewModel>
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>

    <VerticalStackLayout>
        <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding Sections}" x:Name="myCollectionView"
                                Grid.Row="1">
            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <HorizontalStackLayout>
                      
                        <CheckBox Color="#0B4C90" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}">
                            <CheckBox.Behaviors>
                                <toolkit:EventToCommandBehavior
                                    Command="{Binding BindingContext.UpdateThisItemCommand, Source={x:Reference myCollectionView}}"
                                    CommandParameter="{Binding .}"
                                    EventName="CheckedChanged" />
                            </CheckBox.Behaviors>

                        </CheckBox>
                        <Label Text="{Binding SectionName}"
                                       FontSize="20"
                                       FontAttributes="Bold"
                                       TextColor="#0B4C90"/>
                    </HorizontalStackLayout>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        </CollectionView>

        <Button Text="Get Sections" Command="{Binding GetResultCommand}"/>
    </VerticalStackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

**MyViewModel.cs**

```
public class MyViewModel 
{
    public ObservableCollection<Rayon> Sections { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<Rayon>();

    public ICommand GetResultCommand { get; set; }
    public ICommand UpdateThisItemCommand { get; set; }


    public MyViewModel() {
        Sections.Add(new Rayon { SectionName= "section_1"});
        Sections.Add(new Rayon { SectionName= "section_2"});
        Sections.Add(new Rayon { SectionName= "section_3"});


        GetResultCommand = new Command(getResult);

        UpdateThisItemCommand = new Command<Rayon>(checkboxcommand);

    }

    private void checkboxcommand(Rayon obj)
    {
        if (obj != null)
        {
            if (obj.IsChecked)
            {
                // you also need to add some other logic codes here

               
            }
           
        }
    }

    private void getResult()
    {
        foreach (var section in Sections)
        {
            if (section.IsChecked) { 
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(section.SectionName);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Rayon.cs**

```
public class Rayon: INotifyPropertyChanged 
{
    public string SectionName { get; set; }

    private bool _isChecked;
    public bool IsChecked
    {
        set { SetProperty(ref _isChecked, value); }
        get { return _isChecked; }
    }

    bool SetProperty<T>(ref T storage, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (Object.Equals(storage, value))
            return false;
        storage = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
        return true;
    }
    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

**Note:**

Here, we need to install nuget `CommunityToolkit.Maui` and initialize the package correctly.

For more information, you can check document: [Get started](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/maui/get-started?tabs=CommunityToolkitMaui).